# Clock not working I need help, it's not working

Tags: javascript

I followed a tutorial  on YT on how to put a clock, I've copied the exact code (well not exactly because of the "id") mine seems to be not working. this is my code

```
const hourEl = document.getElementsById ("hour");
const minuteEl = document.getElementById("minutes");
const secondsEl = document.getElementById("seconds");
const ampmEl = document.getElementById("ampm");


function updateClock (){
    let h = new Date().getHours();
    let m = new Date().getMinutes();
    let s = new Date().getSeconds();
    let ampm = "AM";

    if(h> 12) {
        h = h - 12; 
        ampm= "PM";
    }

    h = h > 10 ? "0" + h: h;
    m = m > 10 ? "0" + m: m;
    s = s > 10 ? "0" + s: s;
    
    hourEl.innerText = h;
    minuteEl.innerText = m;
    secondsEl.innerText = s;
    ampmEl, (innerText= ampm);
    setTimeout(()=>{
         
    }, 1000)
}

updateClock();
```

Comment: Please be specific; "seems to be not working" isn't particularly helpful. What's the actual result vs expected result? Are there any error messages in the console?

Comment: Your timeout calls nothing, so you run updateClock once, that runs, ends with a scheduled call for "a function that does nothing", and 1 second later, that function runs. And does exactly what you wrote it to do: nothing.

Comment: I tried your code and there is a very clear error in the console. `getElementsById ` is not a function.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly you just need to call the function from your timeout, but then you need to flip your > to < in your comparison, and fix a few typos (document.getElement*s*ById, for example, should be document.getElementById):

```js
const hourEl = document.getElementById ("hour");
const minuteEl = document.getElementById("minutes");
const secondsEl = document.getElementById("seconds");
const ampmEl = document.getElementById("ampm");


function updateClock (){
    
    let h = new Date().getHours();
    let m = new Date().getMinutes();
    let s = new Date().getSeconds();
    let ampm = "AM";

    if(h> 12) {
        h = h - 12; 
        ampm= "PM";
    }

    h = h < 10 ? "0" + h: h;
    m = m < 10 ? "0" + m: m;
    s = s < 10 ? "0" + s: s;
    hourEl.innerText = h;
    minuteEl.innerText = m;
    secondsEl.innerText = s;
    ampmEl, (innerText= ampm);
    setTimeout(()=>{
         updateClock()
    }, 1000)
}

updateClock();
```

```css
div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="hour"></div>:
<div id="minutes"></div>:
<div id="seconds"></div>
<div id="ampm"></div>
```